# Python setuptools doesn't install PyQt5 correctly

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, setuptools

I've run into a problem recently that I don't know if it's a bug or not.

First, le'ts create a virtual environment and activate it:

```
$ python3 -m venv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
```

Then I install PyQt5 manually and run a little test program:

```
(venv) $ pip3 install PyQt5
Successfully installed PyQt5-5.11.3 PyQt5-sip-4.19.13
(venv) $ python3 -c 'from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication'
```

So, this went well and there were no importing error messages. Now, let's start again wit a clean environment (steps omitted) and try to install PyQt5 via setuptools:

```
(venv) $ python3 -c "import setuptools; setuptools.setup(name='Hello', version='0.1', install_requires=['PyQt5'])" install
(...lots of output...)
Installed /home/orestes/Devel/EntornsPython/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5-5.11.3-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg
Installed /home/orestes/Devel/EntornsPython/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5_sip-4.19.13-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg
Finished processing dependencies for Hello==0.1
```

As before, it installs PyQt5 and PyQt5-sip. But now if we execute the test program:

```
(venv) $ python3 -c 'from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.sip'
```

I'm using Python 3.6.7 in an Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic). Setuptools are install ed via regular Ubuntu packages (version 39.0.1). Also tried with local, pip-installed setuptools, with the same result.

Is that a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Probably the wrong import order in `easy-install.pth` - check whether you have the file in the site packages dir (you should have one) and try changing the import order of both eggs.